# Viewing processes, cores, threads and end points of a Azure Service Fabric application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm running the [word count application](https://github.com/Azure/servicefabric-samples/tree/master/samples/Services/VS2015/WordCount) locally on my laptop.

1. How can I find that the end point is http://localhost:8081/wordcount/ without running the application and looking at the log?
2. Please see the TaskManager image. I see that the number of threads being created 27, 29,26 and 19. They are very high compared to being created by other applications. Why these high number of threads and who created these? Is this by the *CreateTransaction* call in the *RunAsync*?
3. What I don't see in the Service Explore is the number of cores being used. Does the Service Fabric use only single core or scale up on the same box if there are multiple cores?

**Processes Information from the Task Manager:**

[image]

**Performance information:**

The value 27,29,26 & 19 are thread counts.

[image]

**Service Fabric Explorer:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For #1:**

You can see this in Service Fabric explorer by clicking on the replica for the WordCountWebService.

[image]

**For #3:**

Service Fabric let's the operating system schedule its threads on whatever cores are available

Comment: Concerning the question #3, do you mean Service Fabric uses TPL to scale up to multiple cores on the same node?